# Can the Android "empty" Fragment constructor can contain some variable inits?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Does "empty" mean no parameters or no content at all?

I need to init some vars in my constructor (some class specific "static" vars inherited from a superclass that my superclass needs for rendering).

So far I do this via a method (see `getLayout()` below).

Can I also do it like in the below constructor?

```
public class StartFragment extends WizardFragment {

    public int getLayout() {
        return R.layout.fragment_start;
    }


    public StartFragment() {
        animatedDrawableId = R.drawable.ask_attach;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far the best solution for me was to have an init method that gets called by the superclass in `onCreateView()`.

In superclass:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    wizardInit();

    ... other code here
}
```

In subclass:

```
@Override
protected void wizardInit() {
    layoutId = R.layout.fragment_drop_ask_for_tag;
    animatedDrawableId = R.drawable.ask_attach;
}
```